# Integrated Graphics Card not recognized Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: intel-graphics, 18.04, integrated

I have an i7-6700K Skylake and from my understanding the processor contains integrated graphics. My computer is not recognizing the integrated graphics with the processor. What would I need to do to use the integrated graphics in the processor?

Comment: 18.04 should know how to use the integrated graphics on a Skylake CPU. Is it using a discrete graphics card instead? If not, why do you think it's not recognizing it?

Comment: I was able to fix the issue. I had to play around in the BIOS a little. For some reason it wasn't enabling it but it's fixed. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @Lumbeezl Can you please tell how did you fix this issue? I ran into similar issue.